# How can I fetch data in real-time from an network device on iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, network-programming, nsurlsession

I have a network-connected device with an web page that shows the device's status in plaintext. I am currently building an iOS app that fetches the status and displays the data on a graph in realtime (refreshes every 250ms).

I am initialising an infinite timer in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchLoop = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, 
                                                       target: self, 
                                                       selector: "fetchLoopExecute", 
                                                       userInfo: nil, 
                                                       repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(fetchLoop, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}
```

And execute this when the timer fires:

```
func fetchLoopExecute() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        var recievedString : String = ""
        do {
            recievedString = try NSString(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"http://\(self.fetchAddr):8461/status")!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
        } catch {
        }
        var v = StatusData()
        v.updateFromString(recievedString)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.labelValueG.text = String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [v.valueG])
            self.labelValueN.text = String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [v.valueN])
            self.labelValueU.text = String(format: "%.3f", arguments: [v.valueU])
            self.updateGraph(v)
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that the code above is using much ram (I see no memory leaks, but the amount of used ram is increasing up to the point where the app crashes) and makes the app laggy in time. What are possible alternative solutions so that I can refresh the data at a high pace automatically without using much ram?

Comment: Are you reading the entire HTML or the link is of a rest service, or something like that? (don't know if NSString supports that)

Comment: Have you timed how long does it take when you make a http request and when the request actually comes back? I bet it takes seconds, not milliseconds. What happens if the request is not done in time? You fire another req. Sorry but this approach is kind of insane.

Comment: NSString() as String ??? why don't you just use String()?

Comment: It is a REST service, the device has a website embedded in which a jQuerry interogation is made every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I've timed the request, it is 0,0249s

Comment: 0.0249 for you doesn't mean that it will be that much for me on my 3G, 4G / LTE connection. Perhaps increase your nstimer to every 1-2 secs. Also put it in a separate global thread.

Comment: The software is for monitoring a device over a LAN connection. The 250ms interval is in my requirements sheet, based on 4 values the software must fine tune some settings. Therefor, the timer needs to fire that often.